# Shape of the view in Appcelerator

Tags: view, appcelerator, shapes

I have designed a rectangular view in appcelerator. I want to make the breadth of this view circular as shown in the image below. Can anyone tell me how this is done?[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property `borderRadius` for that. But keep in mind that it might not look smooth on all devices.

An interesting article about round views is available here: https://medium.com/all-titanium/make-super-smooth-rounded-borders-on-android-titanium-9accbe924fdb